# How to check if value is multiple or not in key value c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here is the method:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var parameters = filterContext.ActionParameters.ToArray();
    if (parameters.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> data in parameters)
        {
            singleparameters = singleparameters + data.Key + ":" + " " + data.Value + ",";

        }
        singleparameters = singleparameters.Remove(singleparameters.LastIndexOf(','));
```

I want to check if data value contain single or multiple value.

If the data is single data then `key:req` and `value: pagerecords:200`.

If the data contains multiple values there then check if values contain array or single value. Fot example: `key:req` and `values: pagerecords:200, pageinfo:"adsa", count:0, filter: records:200,cotnain:"asa"`

I want to check condition an access that..

I am newbie in this area so please give me any suggestion 
     for more clarification
[image: keyvaluepair]

Comment: I find it hard to understand your question

Comment: mm..in short I want to check if value is single or multiple and if multiple then check again if it contain array or just single value  @Cort3z

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by 'single' value or 'multiple' value. In which format do you send parameters? Give a sample, please.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I have added image...I want to check values if it contain single value or multiple and in multiple also it contain array or just single value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> data in parameters)
 {
      if (data.Key == "request" && data.value is jqGridRequest)
      {
       var fields = g.GetType().GetProperties();
       bool hasSingleValue = fields.Count(x => x.GetValue(g, null) != null) == 1;
      }
 }
```

as From screenshot its clear that the data.value type is jqGridRequest, so we can directly make use of the object to check or get the desired value, Actually you dont need to do looping also , Directly cast the object and make use of property using if else.

```
jqGridRequest request = data.value as jqGridRequest;
if (request != null)
{
int  pageindex = request.PageIndex;
//// so on other properties, get it and use it directly without looping. 
}
```

Comment: Thanku so much..its working ..There was second question also that in multiple value if single value there or multiple values..how to check that..

Comment: @debin, that what I meant, the data is internally getting serialized in jqGridRequest, so you can can perform the task you want by setting if condition. But if you really want to know whether its multi or single then u can use   var fields = g.GetType().GetProperties();
       bool hasSingleValue = fields.Count(x => x.GetValue(g, null) != null) == 1; this to know whether its single valued, if it will be single valued then there will all property value null except one, otherwise its multiple.

Comment: thanks for ur reply :) but I got an error while there is a single value `parameter mismatch`..do u have any idea about that?

Answer (score 0):

This can help you check the value is single or multiple:

```
var valueFields = data.Value.GetType().GetFields();
var fieldNumber = valueFields.Length;  
//If fieldNumber = 1 it is single, otherwise it is multiple
```

Then you can check if it contains any array

```
foreach(var fld in valueFields) {
  bool isArray = fld.FieldType.IsArray; //true if the field is an array
}
```

Comment: http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Lib.Web.Mvc/Lib.Web.Mvc/JqGridRequest
from link its clear that JqGridRequest will have properties in stead of fields. so your solution may not work here,

Comment: I haven't used JQGrid so I just assumed it's a normal object :)

Comment: thnx it helped too :)